# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que en un campo donde se ingrese un número se anteponga automáticamente el código del país?

Tags: php

Tengo la siguiente línea con la cual le asigno a la variable un número de teléfono del lado del cliente, pero quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que al ingresar un número se le asigne un código preestablecido

Ej Ingrese número: 0982111777
el resultado debería ser así: **+595**0982111777
es decir debe ir previamente este código **+595**

Esta  es una de las líneas de código:

```
$phone1 = get_post_meta( $id, 'wyz_business_phone1', true );
```

A esta también se le podría enviar:

```
 <?php echo esc_html( $business_data['phone1'] ); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

debes tener el valor previamente cargado de alguna manera, ya sea predefinido o cargado dinamicamente desde la DB, pero deberia ser algo asi:

```
  //declaras una variable en la que almacenas el prefijo
$prefijo = '+595';
  //obtienes el numero de telefono de la forma que vienes usando.
$phone1 = get_post_meta( $id, 'wyz_business_phone1', true );
  //le concatenas el prefijo
$phone1 =$prefijo + $phone1;
```

espero sea lo que necesitas, me cuentas!

Comment: al final lo hice asi `$tel =$prefijo.$tel;` porque si le ponía el + sumaba

Comment: Si tienes un pequeño error de concatenacion, pero bueno esa es la idea adoprtar el codigo a nuestras necesidades, exitos bro

Answer (score 0):

Lo podés concatenar dentro de la viable de la siguiente manera:

```
$business_data['phone1'] = '+595'.$business_data['phone1'];
//A partir de acá la variable ya incluye el prefijo
```

Después guardás el dato como lo hacías antes, sin tener que modificar el guardado.
Solo tené en cuenta que cuando imprimas el dato del lado del cliente te va a quedar con doble prefijo si lo tenés agregado nuevamente.